# PHP OOP + MVC some explanation needed

Tags: php, oop

I'm a rookie with MVC and OOP and I'm trying to learn it with tutorials and by trying some stuff out myself. I've got this code:

Model.class.php:

```
class Model {
    public $string;

    // Add a value to the instance variable $string when object of this class is instantiated
    public function __construct(){
        $this->string = "MVC + PHP = Awesome!";
    }
}
```

Controller.class.php:

```
class Controller {
    private $model;

    // For now, the Controller doesn't do anything, because no controlling features have been implemented yet
    public function __construct($model) {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}
```

My View.class.php:

```
class View {
    private $model;
    private $controller;
    private $account;

    public function __construct($controller,$model) {
        $this->controller = $controller;
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->account = $account;
    }

    // Return the value of the $string variable
    public function output(){
        return $this->model->string;
    }
}
```

This is my index.php where a simple string is echoed, as a result of the code above:

```
$model = new Model();
$controller = new Controller($model);
$view = new View($controller, $model);
$account = new Account();

// Execute the output() function from the View class to output the text
echo $view->output();
```

I've created the account class myself and it should output 'Yoo' instead of 'PHP + MVC = Awesome!' which looks like this:

```
class Account extends Model {    
    // Add a value to the instance variable $string when object of this class is instantiated
    public function __construct(){
        $this->string = "Yoo";
    }
}
```

When I do `return $this->model->string;` it correctly outputs `PHP + MVC = Awesome!`. But when I do `return $this->account->string`, it outputs nothing. No errors or anything. Why isn't this working?

Comment: In the constructor for your `View`, you have `$this->account = $account`, but `$account` is undefined in that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This answer is just a basic example of MVC**

---

### How a complex MVC framework functions

**In very big lines**

In fact your index file should only run an Application class or something that will route the request to the good controller and method. But, well, if you want to take a start, you don't need to make something very complex.

---

### Your error

**(In my opinion)**

Here your main error is thinking that it's your index file that call model, then pass it to controller which you will pass to view. In MVC the controller should be able to do all of this himself, once called.

---

### How it works

**Still in big lines**

Index file instantiate a controller, then call a method of this controller. The controller call the model, that gather data and send it back to controller, which will send this data to the good view (still called by controller), then the view will display the result.

---

### Example

**index.php**

```
<?php
// i have only one controller, with only one action, so i call it.
// i havnt autoloader so i do all requires here

require_once 'MyController.php';
require_once 'MyModel.php';
require_once 'MyView.php';

$Controller = new MyController();
$Controller->exampleAction();
```

**MyController.php**

```
<?php
class MyController
{
    public function exampleAction()
    {
        $model = new MyModel();
        $view = new MyView();
        $view->send($model->data());
    }
}
```

**MyModel.php**

```
<?php
class MyModel
{
    public function data()
    {
        return 'Some data from the model';
    }
}
```

**MyView.php**

```
<?php
class MyView
{
    public function send($data)
    {
        echo $data;
    }
}
```

---

### Go further

By the way, the controller can have a dedicated model, then you can load it in his constructor

**MyController.php**

```
<?php
class MyController
{
    protected $Model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Model = new MyModel();
    }
    public function exampleAction()
    {
        $view = new MyView();
        $view->send($this->Model->data());
    }
}
```

**And same for view.**

---

Hope this answer helped you to understand how MVC works ^^

Comment: Very good answer, thanks! I will study your comment and continue from there. Your explanation clears up a lot of confusions I had.